# C# Multi-level dictionary.where finding results

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm quite new still to C# and I'm getting there slowly, I've searched and can't find anything but I'm looking for a way to fetch only entries with the same tag.

Here's my dictionary setup

```c#
public class CustomClass
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public bool state { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}

public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<CustomClass>>> Status;
```

The way the data looks in JSON, what I'm looking for is a efficient and way to fetching only the data I'm looking for. This JSON data is just an example.

```json
{
  "State1": {
    "Type1": [
      {
        "id": "UNIQUE ID 1",
        "state": true,
        "data": "DUMMY DATA"
      },
      {
        "id": "UNIQUE ID 2",
        "state": true,
        "data": "DUMMY DATA"
      }
    ],
    "Type2": []
  },
  "State2": {
    "Type1": [],
    "Type2": [
      {
        "id": "UNIQUE ID 1",
        "state": true,
        "data": "DUMMY DATA"
      },
      {
        "id": "UNIQUE ID 2",
        "state": false,
        "data": "DUMMY DATA"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Two things I'm looking to to do with this, 1 removing all entries if the `state` is true, another thing I'm looking for is to fetch only entries with `state` being true in which I can read the `data` and use it's value.

Essentially it's kinda like an expiration, if `state` is true, it's no longer relevant meaning it should be considered expired and that's why I need to read the `data`, but I also need an option to clear expired entries.

P.S: This dictionary is fairly big and contains a lot of entries, which is why I rather not do a couple of loops like I know I can do. Looping the first Dictionary, then second, and then the list to find which values.

Comment: How are you parsing the Json to the class? It does not seem to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
            List<CustomClass> classes = new List<CustomClass>();
            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<CustomClass>>> Status = classes
                .Where(x => x.state == true)
                .GroupBy(x => x.id, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.GroupBy(a => a.data, b => b)
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.ToList()));
```